# How to calculate the furthest point on a sphere from multiple points?

Tags: geometry

Given a sphere, the furthest point from any single given point is directly through the centre. This much seems obvious.

The furthest point from two points, I am assuming, is calculated by finding the point at the centre of these two points, and going through the centre from there.

Three points make a triangle. Somehow I’m sure you can find the geographic centre of those three points. Then a line through the spheres centre reveals a nearer and further point on the surface.

But given *n* points with no particular order I’m not even sure how I would start.

Edit: to clarify I’m looking for the longest direct distance across the surface of the sphere. Great Circle Distance?

Edit 2: @user in the comments puts it well: I want to maximize the minimal distance to *n* points

Comment: What metric are you using?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I would guess the distance between two points can be treated as equivalent to the angle between the radii drawn from the center to those two points.

Comment: What makes a point on the sphere furher from multiple points than another? Id est: what function do you wish to maximize?

Comment: Clarified the unit as distance across the surface. But largest angle between the radii would be an equivalent that could be converted.

Comment: You cannot maximize $n$ distances simultaneously. You must give a more specific criterion.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "furthest point from multiple points". What do you want to maximise? The sum of distances from the points? Something else?

Comment: Let’s say I have 7 ex-wives living in seven different locations on earth. Where do I need to move to be as far away from them all as possible? It won’t be equally far from them all, but I want to maximize the distance. (If my wife ever reads this: I promise it’s hypothetical)

Comment: I would assume that you would like to find the point which maximizes the minimal distance to the given points. Is it correct? Alternatively you could intend to minimize the sum of squared distances or something like this.

Comment: Maybe you are after what is known as the Thomson problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem

Comment: Fir a general collection of points in the sphere this is actually a problem in linear programming.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem for a discussion of the planar version.